# How to add theano to anaconda python v2.7 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, theano, ubuntu-16.04

I'm want to install theano into the anaconda package for python v2.7 on ubuntu 16.04. I already installed anaconda to the folder /opt/anaconda. Can some please guide me on how to install Theano package which is accessible by the anaconda packages. I've searched lot on google but not able find a clear solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was recommended to switch back to 14.04 for theano, because t just stopped working on 16.04, but still I am also looking for a solid working guide.
There are some resources that explain how to set up these http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html 
and https://www.jayakumar.org/linux/gtx-1070-on-ubuntu-16-04-with-cuda-8-0-and-theano/

Comment: I got the solution for it. I just need to change the permission of .theanorc file